# Get name of installation directory for pip installed package

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I need to get the installation directory of a Python3 package installed using pip.

I got a package, let's say `mkdocs-mermaid2-plugin`.

```
pip install mkdocs-mermaid2-plugin // being installed to site-packages/mermaid2
```

If I use this package within Python, i can do so `import mermaid2`.

I need a script, which outputs for a given Python package name *mkdocs-mermaid2-plugin* the name of the installation directory.

```
$ ./print-installation-directory-of-package.py mkdocs-mermaid2-plugin
mermaid2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via pip commands

```
pip show mkdocs-mermaid2-plugin
```

this will show all info about that pip package

If you want to get info on what packages are installed you can do

```
pip list
```

Example:

```
pip show xkit
```

returns

```
Name: xkit
Version: 0.0.0
Summary: library for the manipulation of the xorg.conf
Home-page: https://launchpad.net/x-kit
Author: Alberto Milone
Author-email: albertomilone@alice.it
License: GPL v2 or later
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

if you just want to return only the location you can do this by using the following

```
pip show xkit | grep -F Location
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Hopefully I'm blind, but that does not show me the actual installation directory. Keep in mind, that in my example the package  name and installation directory are different.

Comment: the install dir in this example is the location, The above example is ran on linux but should work in the same way for windows

Comment: But I'm searching for /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xkit, not /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (in the xkit case I could just append "xkit" to the "Location: " provided by pip show, but in my example I can't).

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
$ ./print-directory-of-module.py mkdocs-mermaid2-plugin
mermaid2
```

Source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import importlib.metadata
from importlib.metadata import distribution

args = sys.argv[1:]
if len(args) > 0:
  try:
    dist = distribution(args[0])
  except importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError as e:
    print('Package {} not found'.format(e), file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

  pathToTopLevelFile = os.path.join(dist._path, "top_level.txt")
  f = open(pathToTopLevelFile)

  print(f.read().strip())
```

This solution works - but is ugly as hell, there must be a better way.